# Fluent Bit configuration for separating and routing application logs to distinct locations on AWS EKS Fargate

Tags: amazon-s3, logging, amazon-kinesis, aws-fargate, fluent-bit

I'm currently working with AWS EKS Fargate and facing challenges with effectively sending application logs to an AWS S3 bucket. I'm utilizing Fluent Bit as a log router, which routes logs to a Kinesis Firehose stream that eventually sends the logs to an S3 bucket. The issue I'm encountering is that when multiple applications transfer logs simultaneously, the logs get mixed together in the output file within the S3 bucket. This makes it difficult to manage and analyze logs on a per-application basis.

Here's a snippet of my Fluent Bit configuration file:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aws-logging
  namespace: aws-observability
data:
  flb_log_cw: "true"  # Ships Fluent Bit process logs to CloudWatch.
  output.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
     Name  kinesis_firehose
     Match kube.*
     region ap-south-1
     delivery_stream eks-logs-delivery-stream
  filters.conf: |
    [FILTER]
      Name                kubernetes
      Match               kube.*
      Merge_Log           On
      Buffer_Size         0
      Kube_Meta_Cache_TTL 300s
```

I want to find a way to ensure that logs from different applications are properly separated and routed to distinct locations within the S3 bucket. Ideally, I would like to organize the logs in a way that makes it easy to manage and analyze them on an individual application basis. Are there any modifications or additional configuration settings I should consider implementing in Fluent Bit to achieve this goal?